# Keras: Wrong Input Shape in LSTM Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train an LSTM recurrent neural network, for sequence classification.

My data has the following formart:

```
Input: [1,5,2,3,6,2, ...] -> Output: 1
Input: [2,10,4,6,12,4, ...] -> Output: 1
Input: [4,1,7,1,9,2, ...] -> Output: 2
Input: [1,3,5,9,10,20, ...] -> Output: 3
.
.
.
```

So basically I want to provide a sequence as an input and get an integer as an output.

Each input sequence has length = 2000 float numbers, and I have around 1485 samples for training

The output is just an integer from 1 to 10

This is what I tried to do:

```
# Get the training numpy 2D array for the input (1485X 2000). 
# Each element is an input sequence of length 2000
# eg: [ [1,2,3...], [4,5,6...], ... ]
x_train = get_training_x() 

# Get the training numpy 2D array for the outputs (1485 X 1). 
# Each element is an integer output for the corresponding input from x_train
# eg: [ 1, 2, 3, ...]
y_train = get_training_y()

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(x_train.shape)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=3, batch_size=64)
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1485, 2000)
```

I tried using this instead:

```
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(1485, 1, 2000)))
```

But got the another error this time:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Can anyone explain what is my input shape? and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the format of your input and output, you can use parts of the approach taken by one of the official [Keras examples](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py). More specifically, since you are not creating a binary classifier, but rather predicting an integer, you can use one-hot encoding to encode `y_train` using `to_categorical()`.

```
# Number of elements in each sample
num_vals = x_train.shape[1]

# Convert all samples in y_train to one-hot encoding
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)

# Get number of possible values for model inputs and outputs
num_x_tokens = np.amax(x_train) + 1
num_y_tokens = y_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_x_tokens, 100))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(num_y_tokens, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=64,
              epochs=3)
```

The `num_x_tokens` in the code above would be the maximum size of the element in one of your input samples (e.g. if you have two samples `[1, 7, 2]` and `[3, 5, 4]` then `num_x_tokens` is `7`). If you use `numpy` you can find this with `np.amax(x_train)`. Similarly, `num_y_tokens` is the number of categories you have in `y_train`.

After training, you can run predictions using the code below. Using `np.argmax` effectively reverses `to_categorical` in this configuration.

```
model_out = model.predict(x_test)
model_out = np.argmax(model_out, axis=1)
```

You can import `to_categorical` using `from keras.utils import to_categorical`, `Embedding` using `from keras.layers import Embedding`, and numpy using `import numpy as np`.

Also, you don't have to do `print(model.summary())`. `model.summary()` is enough to print out the summary.

**EDIT**

If it is the case that the input is of the form `[[0.12, 0.31, ...], [0.22, 0.95, ...], ...]` (say, generated with `x_train = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_vals)`) then you can use `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))` to change the shape of the array to input it into the LSTM layer. The code to train the model in that case would be:

```
num_samples = x_train.shape[0]
num_vals    = x_train.shape[1] # Number of elements in each sample

# Reshape for what LSTM expects
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)

# Get number of possible values for model outputs
num_y_tokens = y_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(num_vals, 1)))
model.add(Dense(num_y_tokens, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=64,
              epochs=3)
```

The `num_vals` is the length of each sample array in `x_train`. `np.reshape(x_train, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))` changes each sample from `[0.12, 0.31, ...]` form to `[[0.12], [0.31], ...]` form, which is the shape that LSTM then takes (`input_shape=(num_vals, 1)`). The extra `1` seems strange in this case, but it is necessary to add an extra dimension to the input for the LSTM since it expects each sample to have at least two dimensions, typically called `(timesteps, data_dim)`, or in this case `(num_vals, 1)`.

To see how else LSTMs are used in Keras you can refer to:

[Keras Sequential model guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) (has several LSTM examples)

[Keras examples](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples) (look for `*.py` files with `lstm` in their name)

Comment: Adding the Embedding layer fixed the problem with my input shape, however I have another problem. I do not know the num_x_tokens. I cannot take the max because the values there are all floats and values between 0 and 1 (The example in the question might have been missleading, sorry for that). And I do not know the number of input tokens. Any idea how an embedding layer can be used without knowing the token number? (I think there can be millions of different input, considering it's a random float between 0 and 1). Thanks

Comment: In that case, say you defined `x_train = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_vals)`. This will be of the form `[[0.12, 0.31, ...], [0.22, 0.95, ...], ...]`. You can use `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))` to change the shape of the array and then input it into the LSTM layer with `model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(num_vals, 1)))` (and also remove the `Embedding` layer). @Youssef did I interpret your input format correctly?

Comment: Awesome! it worked great. Would you mind adding your comment to your answer and I will accept it. Would be also great if you can explain what does the "1" represent in both the "reshape" and the "input_shape". Is this the dimension of the input? [num_vals x 1 ]?

Answer (score 1):

try reshaping your training data to:

```
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1])
```

Comment: I get the same error I got later: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`. This is still using `model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=x_train.shape))`
Thanks

Comment: change your input_shape too

Answer (score 1):

`input_shape=(None, x_train.shape[1], 1)`, where `None` is the batch size, `x_train.shape[1]` is the length of each sequence of features, and `1` is each feature length. (Not sure if batch size is necessary for `Sequential` model).

And then reshape your data into `x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, x_train.shape[1], 1)`.

Comment: Hello, I now get this error: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4` 

Thanks

Comment: I did exactly what you described by using: 

`input_shape = (None, x_train.shape[1], 1)`
`x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, x_train.shape[1], 1)`

And then changed the LSTM layer to take that input shape

`model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=input_shape))`

Comment: @Youssef Try removing that `None` from `input_shape`.