# Input Shape Keras RNN

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working with a time-series data, that has shape of **2000x1001**, where 2000 is the number of cases, 1000 rows represent the data in time-domain, displacements in X direction during 1 sec period, meaning that the timestep is 0.001. The last column represents the speed, the output value that I need to predict based on the displacements during 1 sec. How the **Input Data** should be shaped for **RNN** in **Keras**? I've gone trough some tutorials, but still I'm cofused about Input Shape in RNN. Thanks in advance

```py
#load data training data
dataset=loadtxt("Data.csv", delimiter=",")
x = dataset[:,:1000]
y = dataset[:,1000]


#Create train and test dataset with an 80:20 split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2) 

#input scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_s =scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_s = scaler.transform(x_test)

num_samples = x_train_s.shape[0] ## Number of samples
num_vals    = x_train_s.shape[1] # Number of elements in each sample

x_train_s = np.reshape(x_train_s, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))

#create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(num_vals, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['mape'])
model.summary()

#training
history = model.fit(x_train_s, y_train,epochs=10, verbose = 1, batch_size =64)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have added an answer, please read it, it will definitely help to understand arguments.

Answer (score 1):

look at this code:
it is trying to predict next 4 values based on previous 6 values.
follow the comments and see how very simple input is manipulated for using it 
as input in rnn/lstm

**follow the comments within code**

````
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN, LSTM

"""
creating a toy dataset
lets use this below ```input_sequence``` as the sequence to make data points.
as per the question, we will use 6 points to predict next 4 points
"""
input_sequence = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

X_train = []
y_train = []


**#first 6 points will be our input data points and next 4 points will be data label.
#so on we will shift by 1 and make such data points and label pairs**


for i in range(len(input_sequence)-9):
    X_train.append(input_sequence[i:i+6])
    y_train.append(input_sequence[i+6:i+10])

X_train = np.array(X_train, dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=np.int32)))


**#X_test for the predictions (contains 6 points)**


X_test = np.array([[8,9,10,1,2,3]],dtype=np.float32)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)


**#we will be using basic LSTM, which accepts input in ```[num_inputs, time_steps, data_points], therefore reshaping as per that```** 
# so here:
# 1. num_inputs = how many sequence of 6 points you want to use i.e. rows (we use X_train.shape[0] )

# 2. time_steps = batches you can considered i.e. if you want to use 1 or 2 or 3 rows

# 3. data_points = number of points (for ex. in our case its 6 points we are using)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

x_points = X_train.shape[-1]
print("one input contains {} points".format(x_points))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, x_points)))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=5, verbose=2)
output = list(map(np.ceil, model.predict(X_test)))
print(output)
````

hope it helps. ask for any doubt pls.

Comment: Hello, I've provided my script in the description. Seems that my question is not clear enough. I have a dataset that has 2000 samples, 1000 displacements in time-domain and corresponding speed which is located at column 1001. My task to make a prediction about the speed based on the displacements. My problem is setting the input shape as it is required for RNN.

Comment: instead of ```x_train_s = np.reshape(x_train_s, (num_samples, num_vals, 1))``` in your code, rewrite it as :  ```x_train_s = np.reshape(x_train_s, (num_samples, 1, num_vals))```.     because format should be (num_samples, timestep, num_vals). please try once.

Comment: did you try the above?

Comment: It works, I also changed `model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(num_vals, 1)))` to `model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(num_vals, 1)))`, but still it's not clear. You mentioned that the format is (num_samples, timestep, num_vals), in my case num_samples = 2000, num_vals is a timestep and equal to 1000, finally number of features is 1, it refers to Y that I'm trying to predict. So, why did you propose (2000, 1, 1000) instead (2000, 1000, 1)?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411333/keras-wrong-input-shape-in-lstm-neural-network) I used this example as the reference

Comment: see, In general input arguments are in order (num_samples, timestep, num_vals). so here in your case, num_samples are 2000(i.e. num of rows), data_points are 1000 and timestep is 1, that's why I said (num_samples, 1, num_vals) i.e. (2000, 1, 1000). hope it clarifies

Comment: Definitely it clarifies, due to lack of experience with RNN I'm still not sure if this design can be applied for my task or whether it's better to use basic MLP, but seems it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: welcome Andrew! definitely this will help you when you somewhere needs to manipulate data for lstms. it will be great if you mark this question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in the [doc](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), Keras expects the following shape for a RNN:

```
(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)
```

- `batch_size` is the umber of samples you feed before a backprop
- `timesteps` is the number of timesteps for each sample
- `input_dim` is the number of features for each timestep

EDIT more details:

In your case you should go for

```
batch_input_shape = (batch_size, timesteps, 1)
```

With `batch_size` and  `timesteps` selected as you wish.

**What about the timesteps?**

Let's say you take one of your 2000 samples, and let's say that your sample has 10 elements instead of 1000, for example:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then, if we chose `timesteps=3`, then you get a batch of length 8:

```
[[[0], [1], [2]],
 [[1], [2], [3]],
 [[2], [3], [4]],
 [[3], [4], [5]],
 [[4], [5], [6]],
 [[5], [6], [7]],
 [[6], [7], [8]],
 [[7], [8], [9]]]
```

Comment: Does this mean that in my case the input has the shape of **(2000,1000,1)**?