# Classify videos with LSTM processed from Inception model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am working on a video dataset(different lengths) with 2 classes in a classification problem.

I am using a pretrained inception v3/Xception model in keras which accept input size of (None,299,299,3) or a frame of size 299x299 and **outputs** features of size **(None,8, 10, 2048)**.

I am trying to pass these output features into another LSTM model for classification but its giving me input_shape error

The LSTM im using is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(None,2048)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

My questions are:

1. Do I need to flatten the output from Inception/Xception model before passing them into the LSTM model?
2. Should the length of all the videos be the same before fitting the LSTM model? What are the advantages/disadvantages of keeping the videos with different lengths?

Comment: Take a look at the doc because a LSTM expects a very specific input shape: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm

Comment: I looked through the docs, it was a bit unclear for me...i referred to this similar article https://dzone.com/articles/video-analysis-to-detect-suspicious-activity-based . They have simply used input_shape=(n_chunks, chunk_size) but it gives me error when I try the same

Comment: You should follow a tutorial as LSTM are truly non-trivial when you've never used them. I wrote a short summary here recently, but I would recommend you to take a real in-depth tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410971/input-shape-keras-rnn/60411073#60411073